# Draw lines using Snap SVG and a JSON object array

Tags: javascript, json, snap.svg

I have following JSON objects within an array, i.e.

```
[{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-1" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-2" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-3" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-4" }]
```

Based on region value, I need to iterate through each of these JSON objects within the array and draw using Snap SVG, lines on the left of an image as well as lines on the right of an image using both the "region" value and  "intrface" values in the above JSON.

When drawing these SVG lines, I also need to place above each of these SVG lines, the values for "intrface" like a label/text, as I iterate each JSON object.

Here is the look of what I am after: assume I'm drawing the inputs (Line-1 and Line-2) coming into a server (my image in the middle) and outputs coming out to the right of the server (Line-3 and Line-4).

Some of the code I have is the following:

```
var my_data = '{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-1" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-2" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-3" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-4" }';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse('[' + my_data + ']');

jsonObj.forEach(function(item,i){
  console.log(item.region + ' - ' + item.intrface);
});
```

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/35pqry60/ ?

Comment: @sielakos thanks but can I ask as I'm new to snapsvg, using your code, 1) how difficult is it to place like a small rectangle between the left and right lines, 2) can we line up line-1 to line-3 and line-2 to line-4, 3) are you able to provide an example of how to add a hyperlink to say on Line-2 and finally 4) change the color(s) of Line-1 and Line-3 to red? Woud really appreciate your help further with the above as the doco in snapsvg is not too clear for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snap assumes some knowledge about svg. You just have to create svg elements and style them using attr method.

Basically you will be using [line](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.line) , [text](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.text) and [rect](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.rect) elements.

The api is pretty much straightforward.

To change fill color of element use fill attribute and for stroke color use stroke attribute.

As for link, I not quite sure how to do that, but you can always add click event to each element and then redirect page to some url using:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

Here is code sample how to do what you want.

```
const data = [{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-1" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-2" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-3" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-4" }];

const s = Snap("#svg");
const height = 40;
const canvasWidth = 400;
const lineWidth = 180;
const rightOffset = canvasWidth/2 - lineWidth;

const leftLines = data.filter((line) => !isRightLine(line));
const rightLines = data.filter(isRightLine);

leftLines.forEach(drawLine);
rightLines.forEach(drawLine);

const numberOfLines = Math.max(leftLines.length, rightLines.length);
const rectSize = 20;
const rectangles = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    rectangles.push(drawRect(i));
}

function drawLine(data, index) {
    const {intrface} = data;
    const isRight = isRightLine(data);
    const x = isRight ? canvasWidth/2 + rightOffset : 0;
  const y = height * (index + 1);
  const stroke = isRight ? 'red' : 'black';

    const line = s.line(x, y, x + 180, y);
  line.attr({
    stroke,
    strokeWidth: 1
  });

  const text = s.text(x + 10, y - 5, intrface);

  text.attr({
    fill: stroke,
    cursor: 'pointer'
  });

  text.click(() => {
    console.log('clicked', data);

    //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
  });
}

function isRightLine({region}) {
    return region === 'RIGHT';
}

function drawRect(index) {
    const x = canvasWidth/2 - rectSize/2;
  const y = height * (index + 1) - rectSize/2;
    const rectangle = s.rect(x, y, rectSize, rectSize);

  rectangle.attr({
    fill: 'black'
  });

  console.log('rr', x, y);

  return rectangle;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/sielakos/pen/eZwrMj

Comment: Thanks @sielakos - I will check it out. Just wondering, with the hyperlink, is this something that SVG can/cannot do based on a standard a href link?

Comment: Im not sure. You would have to check svg specifaction

Comment: No probs - thanks. Just another query re: your text.click(() process, how would I go about only applying a click to a link for specific lines only, like Line-3 and Line-4 only?

Comment: You would have to add event listenerbdepending on some condition or in callback itself check if some codition is true before doing some action, pretty straighforward

Comment: using you codepen sample, I'm trying to replace your two rectangles with two images placed side by side and not top bottom using this code: const img = s.image;
img.attr({
   "xlink:href": "http://lorempixel.com/500/500/",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  });

Comment: And what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Sorry @sielakos, I am not sure how to replace your rectangles in your codepen with an two images that are side by side using the url added in my previous comment - are you able to assist pls.

Comment: I could but it is not my task to implement it for you. I just shown you how to start.

Comment: Understand @sielakos and appreciate your help but I tried the code I provided a few comments up and it didn't work. Are you able to atleast tell me if my code is correct and whether I may have missed something pls. Thanks.

Comment: give me link to codepen or something like that, I will see what I can do to help in my free time.

Comment: hoping you get a chance and come back to me on this question please as I'm not too sure if you saw my other query but I've had to expand on my JSON object to include additional conditions on whether to draw the lines red or green - is there anything in your code example that I need to cater for inorder to capture new conditions? Thanks.